# Move a QGraphicsPixmapItem through keyboard

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, graphics, qgraphicspixmapitem

I have a a character added via QgraphicsPixmapitem and now I want to move it by pressing the arrow keys on the keyboard. But I can't find a way. It gives **compilation error**. Help me please!

moveship.h (header file for my QPixmapItem)

```
#ifndef MOVESHIP_H
#define MOVESHIP_H
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>

class moveship: public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
    public:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
};
#endif // MOVESHIP_H
```

I am just checking if it recognises any key press or not.

Implementation of keyPressEvent:

```
#include "moveship.h"
#include <QDebug>

void moveship::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "moved";
}
```

My main source file:

```
#include<QApplication>
#include<QGraphicsScene>
#include<QGraphicsView>
#include<QGraphicsPixmapItem>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView(scene);

    QPixmap q = QPixmap("://images/player.png");
    if(q.isNull())
    {
        printf("null\n");
    }
    else
    {
        moveship * player = new moveship(q);
        scene->addItem(player);
    }

    view->resize(500,500);
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Please Help :(**

**Edit:**

The **compilation error** which I get is:

> error: no matching function for call to 'moveship::moveship(QPixmap&)'
>            moveship * player = new moveship(q);

Comment: What compilation error? What is `qDebug()` output?

Comment: @dazewell: The compilation error is : "error: no matching function for call to 'moveship::moveship(QPixmap&)'

         moveship * player = new moveship(q);

                                           ^"

Comment: you shoud have updated your question with this notice, because it changes the whole question.
Don't you see what compiler says to you? Check out the signature of your `moveship` constructor. You didn't show it or it doesn't exist at all?

Comment: @dazewell Question edited

Comment: @dazewell sorry for being a noob but I do not know how to solve this problem :(. This is my first experience with qt and I've got this as a school project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's nothing common in the question you ask and the error you get. As I see, you don't have any constructor of your class `moveship`, and that's exactly what compiler is telling to you. There's got to be smth like:

```
moveship(const QPixmap & pixmap, QGraphicsItem * parent = 0)
```

in the header of your class with some implementation, of course and as I see, it's trivial:

```
moveship::moveship(const QPixmap & pixmap, QGraphicsItem * parent = 0) 
                 : QGraphicsItem(pixmap, parent);
```

That's the base knowledge you should have when using c++. Here's nothing special about Qt. I advise you to learn c++ a bit.

BTW, reimplemented `...event(...)` functions is recommended to place in the `protected` part of the class and also declare it to be `virtual`.

Comment: Wouldn't the parent constructor be called automagically ? My guess was the argument was wrong... my guess was wrong...

Comment: @Thalia no, it won't. There will be default constructor created `moveship();`, and it doesn't have QPixmap as an argument and that's what causes the error. My implementation **does** call parent's constructor with given to the child class parameters.

Comment: thanks a lot @dazewell. I know that was quite stupid on my part. Apologies.